# error: no matching function for call to '__invoke_r'

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction, packaged-task

The following simplified code introduces a function `http_GET()` that is based on a custom `async` implementation that takes a callback as parameter. The `async` function creates a (here temporary) object `entity` which allows a `std::future` to be exctracted via `get_future()`. This future should fit the return value of the callback function (`std::future<response>`).

Now I've got a problem in what I believe is the construction of the `entity` object, in that the internal function  `__invoke_r` can't find the right overload. I'm not really sure why this is. I first thought it was because the return value of the callback (in this case `response{}`) couldn't be deduced properly. However gcc actually deduces that right as I see in the errors. What am I missing?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjEIADsABykAA6oCoRODB7evv6p6ZkCIWGRLDFxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn5c1bVZDU0EJRHRsXoKjc2teR0jvf1lFRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmm24EAJ4pmAD6BMRMhApH2CYaAIJbO3uYh8doDGspBAemyer3ef0%2B3zcbBYJFOl2ImAUy1WmEezzeZm24K8ByObioXj%2BdWYtDRoMxHxxXzxBC8KXoZIxWN2VMhyBG%2BFQjLBLNxxy8jlohFO3Ip2L5J3OVxud0BouZELxBNpCO5ry8GSM%2BzEtFQoiIxGu3wAIvsOSAQCkWHFLZ5TjDiCkEHhkJcdXqmAa8eaQFFTgRUcCjlZQaGXgGWPTPdTjmcLsw2PsAEqMkbELwOfaMRxndEmeIht6vfYl/YRqMByFxxisL5uKKPfYIgCOXjwCIU%2BwgPt%2BaYzjii9EuVGIqBY3oI6AtKSYyAA1kxgJh0NcmAo53ikxB5o9SPt648d8XS9nhRAD2YAGzmS/7KgMPfu/UkI1Pz0kE2HAv541Hl6lgD9hAUtGnXS58wsM1JwtGEADdMGoBh5i/Y10QAiC82PEsf0w/9SyYAVUH2JcCGHAUVgQ5CAFpGx9ZUKM3RsMKwwCERVBgoKnEB6NVY4UyDb94lQzZC3QoTcIAn0Z3nRdl1XddN23RtQLncCRLzcT1LDcsDErGkpQTOsoj3atDIAOgs/YXmIYAFD3H0MgAL2lCyzP2ABJRkCKIbUFFOP5LjwSNaDdWhdWQc8GyvG87wfTiLVpelAzcazbNc5S6XoezoJAUIsFUS4lFbRg1jxdz0uBajaJynjkqwXZq0Q7scpIsrHmari4IQxL6HmeZXL67lvxYtiVg409c2OeraEa%2B8OotVrjk84F5pALqIB6zA%2BoGncVpMABWCx70/OiSAAdyadA8QPFb70WfZXP2KImlsk6WswAg2pWn11s2wb9uNbd9hYAUmEHalhrwwDALm07iAu4grqmzAGqlCBnpshRduwdGXqxgbgzQ6GUOyrjFrcH08swAqiq8ErkvKizHgtJzKPan7UHgjbMq27aSLIlU2a0t5xO0zBgujKsDNrfdjLLaW2Ee1K7PikBWeuR7lpBF5vKItd/NdIL6UuBhUCfSKbxi%2B9SYSnm8WVirsDLHmbdyhh8sKzBir%2BBnHaq4FVdqvFptmhhVvJrXVt%2Bnntoswag1BSGANG4hxsEYVg5Rma0dh97PqW9mcujpLY7M%2BOcYOo6OKOU04YRpG3BunG7r3R6MdemvVYjwvOs57qY53AGgZBxpwa/UTiYA3OuP4eHLsz1GLlxzHseX2z%2BrjwmWLE38zP52qlOFnCxYlgN9PjGX6xMhXMCVzGvMI3yDbMC3oqvWK92Vy2r0evG/2YqG2pH6bTejPc6l03QKGuDzVas96723vitP%2BBNhYAV7AGVQKRiCq3VgQfYyBBAnTwM5VAVBXIQGVrtQsRMSx4CoPggQIxqZYK7A5WskCJxcQRF1S4yBYIIioNcThtskqXBqOLbMeICEECoh0fYIc0Z/TRMCR8YUPQGiEZVceNDAJYNCAQKgEBzBmDOoQBA2o1HPmIAdNwDBjFUJ0cnD6Y0n4BSNiFc2dd57HCbohe6XjEYL2zkvJRK0/quxYEwOcVwqY0y9nTH2UjBCyLRIJX8W9AE/izLQJQ2jt6lj0YIQxxjTEEAQMsPBb4vT7VsfYjJk8U4cX1m44KJszaWNgeAwJPiGy3SQq7OB3i3AKJCTHdq4TVaROiYFd21NPbe1Kj8QQqSrBCQcSxY%2BItUJhj7JmDsaQGBKA0qs4S1DXi632AgAgBAUiXAAOLYAACqrStDaNMoRgD7BWLQf%2BSdSyNNccgF%2BlcDqA3QarV5LMbgfJit8ncfzoYAv2Yw1EaT6mlh/BEvuEA4XrK2bhfRwM7hh1%2BRPEsVSXyVMse%2BaxR8WIXOVJ%2BK5Nz7lPKMWYMwzKUggAAPQ8pYKcMy3yzJoHHByvFP4OCLFoJwfavA/AcC0KQVAnA3DWGsGaZEaxDiYh4KQAgmgpWLDnCAfaGgzJcAAJxSHiBoRIkhJBmC4JiS8%2BhOCSHlYa5VnBeAKBABofVhrFhwFgEgamKNCJkAoBAPGyhDA1CEOUs6Cq9WipSHQT0WQ41hFoIm1AyavVproEMWyzAUgKHKQQUgRb6DEAAPICjzQWxVvBw3IGVj6wIqgUYNHwAq3g/BBAiDEOwKQMhBCKBUOoFtpBdAdAMEYFA6rLD6DwFEP1kBFioABFkP1HAqIchrqYSw1gzAaH2FRAA6jqX1WrR22EnKEbNCak0pt4DcTA6w9VnVuNy7gUq3UcDlaQBVSqVUcGwN25Akb9iqESJeKil5JDEWQMgLsNxCRzmQueZdNh9i4EIB%2BLYXB5jvqDYsBAmAmBYDiNuUgJrJCWrMokO1%2B0zDWv2vtJI8QkOAY9aQFgEgNABtA7wcDvr/WBpbX1QDZhPUzvE1JrQMn4LEAyM4SQQA%3D%3D)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>
#include <memory_resource>
#include <functional>
#include <tuple>
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <future>

using allocator_t = std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<std::byte>;


template <typename R>
struct entity
{

    template <typename Cb> requires (std::constructible_from<std::packaged_task<R()>, Cb>)
    entity(Cb&& fn, allocator_t allocator = {})
        :   task_{ std::move(fn) }
    {

    }

    auto get_future() -> std::future<R> {
        return std::future<R>{};
    }

    std::packaged_task<R()> task_;
};

template <typename Cb, typename... Args, std::size_t... I>
auto async_impl_alloc(Cb&& fn, std::tuple<Args...> tuple, std::index_sequence<I...>) -> std::future<decltype(fn(std::get<I>(std::move(tuple))...))>
{
    return entity<decltype(fn(std::get<I>(std::move(tuple))...))>([fn = std::forward<Cb>(fn), ... bargs = std::get<I>(std::move(tuple))]() mutable {
            fn(std::forward<decltype(bargs)>(bargs)...);
        }, std::get<std::index_sequence<I...>::size()>(std::move(tuple))).get_future();
}

template <typename Cb, typename... Args, std::size_t... I>
auto async_impl_noalloc(Cb&& fn, std::tuple<Args...> tuple, std::index_sequence<I...>) -> std::future<decltype(fn(std::get<I>(std::move(tuple))...))>
{
    return entity<decltype(fn(std::get<I>(std::move(tuple))...))>([fn = std::forward<Cb>(fn), ... bargs = std::get<I>(std::move(tuple))]() mutable {
            fn(std::forward<decltype(bargs)>(bargs)...);
        }).get_future();
}

template<typename Cb, typename... Args>
auto async2(Cb&& fn, Args&&... args)
{
    auto tuple = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    constexpr std::size_t cnt = sizeof...(Args);

    if constexpr (std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<std::tuple_element<cnt-1, decltype(tuple)>>, allocator_t>) {
        printf("with allocator\n");
        return async_impl_alloc(std::forward<Cb>(fn), std::forward<decltype(tuple)>(tuple), std::make_index_sequence<cnt-1>{});
    } else {
        printf("without allocator\n");
        return async_impl_noalloc(std::forward<Cb>(fn), std::forward<decltype(tuple)>(tuple), std::make_index_sequence<cnt>{});
    }
}

struct response
{};

auto http_GET(std::pmr::string url)
{
    return async2([](const std::pmr::string& url){
        return response{};
    }, std::move(url));
}

int main()
{
    allocator_t allocator;

    auto fut = http_GET("http://my.url.com");
}
```

Error:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20230123/include/c++/13.0.1/future:1491:41: error: no matching function for call to '__invoke_r<response>(async_impl_noalloc<http_GET(std::pmr::string)::<lambda(const std::pmr::string&)>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char> >&&, 0>(http_GET(std::pmr::string)::<lambda(const std::pmr::string&)>&&, std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<char> >&&>, std::index_sequence<0>)::<lambda()>&)'
 1491 |             return std::__invoke_r<_Res>(_M_impl._M_fn,
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1492 |                                          std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Also if someone knows an easier way to deduce return values of the Callbackb `fn` that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Is this the shortest reproducible example? :(

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes unfortunately. But I already found the bug... The return  value of the inner lambda which is forwarded as callback to std::packaged_task<R()> constructor of course needs to have the return value of the outer callback, otherwise they don't match :) I had to read my own question again to understand what was going on

Comment: @glades Sounds like a perfect opportunity to answer your own question to give others with similar problems some help. :)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Honetly, it looks like an obscure typo to me, not very useful to others.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, that's the other option. Close as a typo :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Close as typo pls. There are simpler questions with the same problem.